# Symmetric self-referential many-to-many

Tags: database-design, foreign-key, constraint, relational-theory

I'm trying to model a hierarchy of categories where a category can have multiple parents ( an overlapping tree model as described [in this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439819890) )

I have the following tables

```
video_categories
  int     id
  string  name

video_category_links
  int     parent_id  (foreign_key to video_categories.id)
  int     child_id   (foreign_key to video_categories.id)
```

and an index on [ parent_id, child_id ] for uniqueness

The issue with this setup is that 
**A** can be parent of **B**, and **B** can be parent of **A** at the same time

Is there a way to specify a db constraint to avoid this or should I ensure it at the application level?

Thank you very much

Comment: Maybe you could use a trigger on insert to check if inserting the new record would create a cycle and throw an error if it does?

Comment: Unless you're prepared to implement some kind of additional constraint, such as that suggested by Alex Kuznetsov - which I think is probably too restrictive - then you can't use declarative constraints to prevent cycles.  Cycles could happen at multiple degrees, e.g. A>B>C>A and so forth.  This has to be handled with application logic.  Declarative constraints only go as far as fields within one record or the key of a record referencing a key in one other record.

Comment: @JoelBrown: Actually, I was thinking that the trigger could call a procedure (assuming the OP's environment supports that) that does deep testing for cycles - but there would probably be a bit of a performance hit.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Agreed, that is how I would do it.  While the trigger is declarative the procedure for cycle checking that would be performed by the trigger is ultimately procedural.  That's why I said you can't do it declaratively.  I guess I should have said _strictly_ declarative.

Comment: @JoelBrown can you please elaborate on your " probably too restrictive" concern - which legitimate scenarios does it disallow?

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov Your assumption is that a category is only ever at one particular level, regardless of how many trees the category participates in.  It is conceivable that a category may be level 2 in one tree and level 4 in another tree, and so on.  If that type of complexity is not required then your solution is elegant and effective.

Comment: @JoelBrown actually I am assuming only one graph, not tree, and the level is the level in this one graph. For multiple graphs, I would have to add another table. I can elaborate if you are interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would define levels in the hierarchy:

```
video_categories
  int     id
  int level
  string  name
```

I would propagate the parent and child levels into your link table:

```
video_category_links
  int     parent_id  
  int parent_level ((parent_id  , parent_level) foreign_key to video_categories(id, level))
  int     child_id   
  int child_level((child_id  , child_level) foreign_key to video_categories(id, level))
  check(child_level > parent_level)
```